# PHP - Generate variations of English phrases and sentences

Tags: php, regex

I would like to generate a variation of English sentences given an original string. I know that I can do some basic search and replace which keeping the sentence grammatically correct. But is there a way to do a more complex rephrasing of sentences?

For example, given a sentence, "A cat is looking at the dog", I want to come up with "Cat is staring at dog" and "The cat is looking at a dog". Sorry, I can't come up with a cleverer example!

Comment: Nothing yet, but I meant I can easily regex for "A" and replace it with "The". I am wondering if there is something already out there that can recreate sentences...

Comment: Maybe [Markov Chains](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/assignments/markov.html) could be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found Microsoft's 'Paraphrase' API. Seems something like what I could use...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847648.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well in general natural language is a more complex type of grammar than regular expressions can capture. So in general the answer is no. On the other hand if the scope you want is limited enough, than regexps might be enough. However I wouldn't sweat it too hard, it fundamentally will be a limited solution.

For a toolkit that will allow you to do more, checkout [NLTK](http://nltk.org) (Python only).

For some more background on why Regexps are of limited use for natural language read [Chomsky Hierarchy on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). It is speculated that English is at [least a context-free language](http://cs.haifa.ac.il/~shuly/teaching/08/nlp/complexity.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. This was useful. I also found an API solution from MS I entered as an answer below.